# ¿Cómo subir pagina web de CodeIgniter con FileZilla a servidor?

Tags: codeigniter, filezilla

tengo dudas para subir una página web desarrollada con el framework CodeIgniter conectada a MySQL, ya inicie sesión en FileZilla. Mis dudas son:

**-Arrastro mi carpeta taller a FileZilla?**

**-Como se sube la Base de Datos?**

**-La base_url se cambia o queda como localhost/Taller?**

Comment: despues de q te conectaste a tu servidor, y te colocaste en la raiz `http_public` tienes que subir ahi el archivo **index.php** y las carpetas **applications** y **systems** mas las que generes como **assets**, etc, despues en `applications/config/config.php` tienes q cambiar tu base_url a la de tu dominio, asi como los datos de acceso a tu database como los creaste o te los dieron, si creaste tu archivo **htaccess** tambien lo tienes que subir por aqui normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que conectarte a tu servidor con FileZilla, FileZilla es el puente que hará que llegues al ftp de tu servidor para subir los recursos. Supongamos que ya estás conectado a tu servidor, ahora lo que tienes que hacer es arrastrar tu proyecto hacia algun lugar del servidor. Puede ser en raíz si gustas.

La base de datos se sube en un servidor de base de datos que es independiente al FileZilla. O sea un MySQL pero online donde importarás tu BD y luego lo conectarás en tu conexion.php o en el archivo de configuraciones de base de datos del CodeIgniter. Este archivo de conexion.php debe tener los datos del servidor MySQL online, o sea su ip o hostname más su usuario y contraseña.

La base_url será midominio.algo/Taller donde "midominio.algo" es el host que adquiriste (normalmente pagarías por uno, aunque puedes conseguirlo gratis) para subir tu app, o sea al que te conectaste por el FileZilla.

Si pones tu aplicación en una carpeta (no raíz) del servidor en FileZilla entonces este será la url: midominio.algo/lacarpeta/Taller

Espero haberme explicador bien, tu pregunto es un poco amplia.

Comment: muchas gracias deja lo checo y si me explicaste bien

Answer (score 1):

La instalación de Codeigniter, como te han comentado, es muy sencilla:

- Subir los archivos al FTP, en la carpeta public_html (o similar, dependiendo del hosting).
- Configurar la base de datos en `application/config/database.php`
- Cambiar la `$base_url` en el archivo `application/config/config.php`

Con esto deberías tener tu sitio funcionando en tu hosting.

#### Mejorar la seguridad

Si bien, puedes hacer algún paso más para mejorar la seguridad. Las carpetas *system* y *application* pueden intentar ocultarse del dominio público para evitar acceso a ellas. Ambas cuentan con archivos *.htaccess* que impiden su acceso directo, pero no sería mala idea si tu web es algo compleja y esperas tener cierto grado de "peligrosidad" a ataques, hacer uno de estos dos métodos (o ambos):

**Método 1: Renombrarlas**

Puedes cambiar el nombre de las carpetas *system* y *application* al nombre que quieras, incluso a una cadena de caracteres del estilo `jbakjsggpoiqjw`.

Una vez cambiado el nombre, tendrás que editar el `index.php` que tienes en tu carpeta raíz, y cambiar los valores de `$system_path` y `$application_folder` con los valores que hayas elegido.

**Método 2: Colocarlas fuera de la carpeta pública**

Para lograr la mejor seguridad, ambas carpetas *system* y *application* deben colocarse por encima del directorio raíz de tu web, para que no puedan ser accesibles desde un navegador de ninguna manera.

Como te decía, las carpetas contienen un archivo `.htaccess` que impide el acceso directo a las mismas, pero es conveniente realizar este método para que, en caso de que el servidor haga algún cambio inesperado a este archivo o, simplemente, no lo hiciera caso por algún motivo, no se pueda acceder a las carpetas.

Para hacerlo, coloca las carpetas fuera de tu public_html (al mismo nivel, por ejemplo) y edita de nuevo el archivo `index.php`. Allí, cambia las variables `$system_path` y `$application_folder` para que coincidan con tu nueva ruta. Preferiblemente, utiliza rutas completas como */www/usuario/system* o la ruta que corresponda en tu hosting.

Si quieres puedes mantener el directorio de vistas (*views*) público. Puedes moverlo fuera de la carpeta *application* a tu raíz, y editar la variable `$view_folder` en el `index.php` con la nueva ruta.

Answer (score 0):

Debes exportar tu base de datos local e importarla en tu servidor

- Subes toda tu carpeta del proyecto a la carpeta public o www de tu servidor.
- -Cambias tu archivo config con tu dominio
- cambias servidor, usuario, password y bdatos de database.php
- Listo!